# Ribbon save action triggered even after using return false [Page Layout Edit mode]

Tags: sharepoint-online, javascript, office-365, page-layout, ribbon

I have an article page where I need to do some custom validations in Edit mode(page layout). **I am trying to cancel the save action using `return false` but the page is still saved.**

```
$('span[id="Ribbon.EditingTools.CPEditTab.EditAndCheckout.SaveEdit-Large"]').click(function(){
        //validations
     if(//validationsfail){
      return false;
     }
});
```

Comment: Are you very sure the original onclick event is on this exact DOM element?

Comment: you should using *PreSaveAction()* for your validate.

Answer (score 1):

Subscribing to the click events is not a good idea here, for many reasons (including: you'd have to consider all buttons user can press to validate the page (in ribbon, in the page...), key events, and also your Handler may happen *after* the SharePoint handler).

The good practice here, to intercept the save action and possibly cancel it, is to define a function called `PreSaveAction`. It will be automatically called by SharePoint before posting the data to the server. See for instance http://www.ilikesharepoint.de/2014/06/sharepoint-presaveaction-helps-for-actions-before-saving-an-item/ or http://sympmarc.com/2009/05/28/validation-on-sharepoint-forms-part-four/ for an example.

Comment: Thanks. Using PreSaveAction was my first thought but i don't think it is available in Page Layout Edit Mode.